# How do I make image ignore safe area and go over the selfie cam at the top

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to make the image to ignore safe areas and reach the top of the phone (past the camera and where time is shown)

This is the code I have right now::

```
import SwiftUI

struct ArtistView: View {
    
    var artist: Artist
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Image("theWeeknd_banner")
                    .resizable()
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 300)
                    // .offset(y: -59)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's just under the selfie camera but I want to have it at the top of the phone like shown in the screenshot. Offsetting it by `y: -59` brings it to the top on a device like iPhone 15 Pro but its too much for the SE. This is the closest I got to getting the result I want.

[image]

I've also tried this from another post:

```
struct ArtistView: View {
    
    var artist: Artist
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                Color.clear
                    .background(
                        Image("theWeeknd_banner")
                            .resizable()
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's at the top but goes over the top and cuts off a bit of the image.

[image]

If anyone could help with the image filling into a certain a height (so it would have the height it needs to be and zoomed in a bit of the width is too much) it would be nice too.

Hopefully it's enough info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the image to scroll with the main content, one way would be to put a `GeometryReader` around the `ScrollView`, to measure the screen size and the safe area insets.

- The `ScrollView` should ignore safe areas at the top and sides.
- The main content should be given a minimum width equal to the screen width.
- Apply the safe area insets as padding to the main content.
- The image can be shown as the background behind the main content.
- Use `alignment: .top` if the top part of the image should always be visible.
- If you want the image to have a minimum height then this can be achieved by applying a minimum height to the actual content.
- Apply `.clipped` below the image, if you don't want it overflowing past the main content.

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("Main content")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: proxy.size.width)
            .padding(.top, proxy.safeAreaInsets.top)
            .padding(.leading, proxy.safeAreaInsets.leading)
            .padding(.trailing, proxy.safeAreaInsets.trailing)
            .frame(minHeight: 200)
            .background(alignment: .top) {
                Image(systemName: "tortoise.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    .background(.green)
            }
            .clipped()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: [.top, .leading, .trailing])
    }
}
```

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.clipped()` modifier to clip the image to avoid going over the top if you want to use `ignoreSafeArea()`

or if you want to set dynamic offset according to the device, you can use `geometryReader()` to get the safe area based on the current device (Ex: iPhone 15 Pro, SE )

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    ScrollView {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Color.clear
                .background(
                    Image("theWeeknd_banner")
                        .resizable()
                        .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: .infinity, height: 300)
                        .offset(y: -geometry.safeAreaInsets.top)
                )
        }
    }
}
```